# SUMIFS with OR criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs

[image: Sample Table]

I want to add values in Column C with the conditions that `Column B = 0`, AND `Column A = "a" OR "b"`

From what I've searched, this would work, but only in excel:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,0,A:A,{"a","b"}))`

I've tried adding "ArrayFormula" as this is a supposedly 'fix' for the above formula for Google Sheets (but tbf, I've only seen it used in COUNTIFS not SUMIFS)

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,0,A:A,{"a","b"})))`

My expected result should be 4 but it keeps on returning 1. Weirdly, if I switch "a" and "b", it would return 3. As if it doesnt take the second criteria into account.

Ive been searching for days now, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C:C, B:B=0, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "a|b")))
```

Answer (score 4):

@player0 has a top solution, but if you want to use `sumifs()`, then try:

```
=sumifs(C:C,B:B,0,A:A,"a")+sumifs(C:C,B:B,0,A:A,"b")
```

Or

```
=arrayformula(sumifs(C:C,B:B,0,regexreplace(A:A,"a|b","a"),"a"))
```

It can also be done with `query()`:

```
=query({A:C},"select sum(Col3) where Col2=0 and Col1 matches 'a|b' label sum(Col3) '' ",0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt think of adding the sumifs because in my original sheet, the formula was already so long. But thanks for the alternatives, I tried it all and they all worked. Would keep them in mind in the future.